# XCTest blurred, not running

Tags: xcode, xctest

Currently working on a project where the Unit tests XCTest are all blurred like so:

[image]

I'm thinking probably the test are disabled somehow.
Does anyone know how I can get them to run?

Comment: Restart Xcode, clean and rebuild, delete DerivedData folder – doing one of those should fix it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can run the unit tests by doing a right click on the test bungle and choosing Run in a context menu. You can also enable unit tests from the same context menu
[image]